# Can I do For loop on Google Script?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to put some information of my sheet in a array, to use in a  graphic later. But this error keeps showing :(

> Error: Syntax error (line 8, archive "Código")

```js
function onOpen() {
  var proposta = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Proposta de solução');
  var ids = proposta.getRange('A10:A26');
  var names = proposta.getRange('B10:B26');
  var esforcos = proposta.getRange('F10:F26');

  var name = [
    for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    names.getCell(i, 1).getValue();
    }
]

  var id = [
    for(var j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
    ids.getCell(j,1).getValue(); 
    }
]

  var esforco = [
    for(var k = 0; k < 17; k++) {
    esforcos.getCell(k,1).getValue();
    }
]
```

}

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the text and error message into your post as text? That makes the question much more useful than it being an image. But basically it looks like you're trying to use a for loop *inside* a variable initialization expression.

Comment: Sorry! I'll fix it!

Comment: Stack Snippet should be used only for executable HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This should get the results you want:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var proposta = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Proposta de solução');
  var ids = proposta.getRange('A10:A26');
  var names = proposta.getRange('B10:B26');
  var esforcos = proposta.getRange('F10:F26');

  var name = [];
  var id = [];
  var esforco = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    name.push(names.getCell(i, 1).getValue());
    id.push(ids.getCell(i, 1).getValue());
    esforco.push(esforcos.getCell(i, 1).getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: You should include references to Apps Script best practices, indicating prominently that this method in your answer is an extremely slow and wasteful method to populate a JavaScript Array from data held in Google Sheets. Consider also mentioning why OP was receiving the `SyntaxError` (e.g. referencing the relevant array literal syntax documentation on your preferred JavaScript language reference).

Comment: Stack Snippet should be used only for executable HTML/CSS/JavaScript